# How do I remove an outer array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ramda.js

I am looping through a nested object. The return data is wrapped by two arrays. I understand why that is, but I do not understand how to get the desired data back.

```
const data = {
  "foo": {
    "bar": {
      "id": "1",
      "step": [{
        "id": "33",
        "copy": [{
            "id": "1",
            "text": "hello",
          },
          {
            "id": "2",
            "text": "whirl",
          },
          {
            "id": "3",
            "text": "whoa",
          }
        ],
      }]
    }

  }
}

pipe(
  path(['foo', 'bar', 'step']),
  map(step => 
    step.copy.map(s => ({text: s.text}))
  )
) (data)
```

the return data returns this:

```
[[{"text": "hello"}, {"text": "whirl"}, {"text": "whoa"}]]
```

I want to return this back:

```
[{"text": "hello"}, {"text": "whirl"}, {"text": "whoa"}]
```

Comment: The inner array is an element of the outer. How do you normally get the first element of an array? ;)

Comment: What happens when step contains more than one element?

Comment: Hi if you want get normal object to particular array try do this way convert JSON Stringify .  var myJSON = JSON.stringify(data);
                  JSON.parse(myJSON).foo.bar.step

Comment: Question: as `step` is written in its singular form, does it make sense to have it as an array of only one object? If it can have many objects, I'd rename it to `steps`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `step` is itself an `array`. You need to get its first item or pass `0` in arguments. Here is a pure js version of finding data from path. I used `reduce()`

```js
const data = { "foo": { "bar": { "id": "1", "step": [{ "id": "33", "copy": [{ "id": "1", "text": "hello" }, { "id": "2", "text": "whirl" }, { "id": "3", "text": "whoa" } ] }] } } }

function getFromPath(obj, path) {
  return path.reduce((ac, a) => ac[a] || {}, obj);
}
let res = getFromPath(data, ["foo","bar","step",0,"copy"]).map(({text}) => ({text}))
console.log(res)
```

Comment: I didn't think of reduce, nice. I also think wanted to change the value and output. Good example.

Comment: What are you talking about? I was complimenting you Jeez. Did you not read good example? What are you attacking me.

Comment: @Raymond Oh sorry. I got a downvote and at the same time ur comment. I am sorry I deleted my cmntt

Answer (score 1):

One solution using **Ramda.js** to achieve what you need is to pipe a [R.flatten](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#flatten) after the `R.map()`.

```js
const data = {
  "foo": {
    "bar": {
      "id": "1",
      "step": [{
        "id": "33",
        "copy": [
          {"id": "1", "text": "hello"},
          {"id": "2", "text": "whirl"},
          {"id": "3", "text": "whoa"}
        ],
      }]
    }
  }
}

let res = R.pipe(
  R.path(['foo', 'bar', 'step']),
  R.map(step => step.copy.map(s => ({text: s.text}))),
  R.flatten
) (data)

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Alternative, another solution coluld be replacing the outter `R.map()` by a [R.reduce()](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#reduce):

```js
const data = {
  "foo": {
    "bar": {
      "id": "1",
      "step": [{
        "id": "33",
        "copy": [
          {"id": "1", "text": "hello"},
          {"id": "2", "text": "whirl"},
          {"id": "3", "text": "whoa"}
        ],
      }]
    }
  }
}

let res = R.pipe(
  R.path(['foo', 'bar', 'step']),
  R.reduce((acc, curr) => acc.concat(curr.copy.map(({text}) => ({text}))), [])
) (data)

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest fix I see to your code is to replace the outer [`map`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#map) with [`chain`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#chain).  You could alternatively follow it with [`flatten`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#flatten) or, better, [`unnest`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#unnest), but `chain` can be thought of (at least when applied to arrays; it's actually more general) as `map` followed by `unnest`.

That would do what you want.  But I would suggest that if you're going to use point-free Ramda code for the rest of it, that you also replace your internal lambdas to get to something like this:

```js
const transform = pipe(
  path(['foo', 'bar', 'step']),
  chain(prop('copy')),
  project(['text'])
)

const data = {"foo": {"bar": {"id": "1", "step": [{"copy": [{"id": "1", "text": "hello"}, {"id": "2", "text": "whirl"}, {"id": "3", "text": "whoa"}], "id": "33"}]}}}

console.log(transform(data))
```

```html
<script src="//bundle.run/ramda@0.26.1"></script>
<script>
const {pipe, path, chain, prop, project} = ramda
</script>
```

This looks good to me.  But note that destructuring makes this much cleaner to do with raw JS than it used to be.  This should also work:

```js
const transform = ({foo: {bar: {step}}}) => step.flatMap(
  ({copy}) => copy.map(({text}) => ({text}))
)

const data = {"foo": {"bar": {"id": "1", "step": [{"copy": [{"id": "1", "text": "hello"}, {"id": "2", "text": "whirl"}, {"id": "3", "text": "whoa"}], "id": "33"}]}}}

console.log(transform(data))
```

In this case, the Ramda version reads more easily to me, but there's only a small difference.

Comment: You can use Array.flatMap instead of Array.map and then Array.flat.

Comment: @OriDrori: Yes, of course.  Thank you.  It's updated with that.  It seems funny that I didn't think of that when I was proposing replacing `map > unnest` with `chain`.

Answer (score 0):

Since copy contains an array, you need to specify you we're going to loop through that array. And you had the right idea, then change the value.

> This

`step.copy.map(s => ({text: s.text}))`

> Needs to be

`data['foo']['bar']['step'][0]['copy'].map(s => ({text: s.text}))`

**or** `data.foo.bar.step[0].copy`

```
data.foo.bar.step.map(v => {
    return v.copy.map(v => {
        return { text: v.text}
    })
});
```

> Example

```js
const data = {
  "foo": {
    "bar": {
      "id": "1",
      "step": [{
        "id": "33",
        "copy": [{
            "id": "1",
            "text": "hello",
          },
          {
            "id": "2",
            "text": "whirl",
          },
          {
            "id": "3",
            "text": "whoa",
          }
        ],
      }]
    }

  }
}
// Output: [{"text": "hello"}, {"text": "whirl"}, {"text": "whoa"}]
let sorted = data['foo']['bar']['step'][0]['copy'].map(s => ({text: s.text}))
// let sorted = data.foo.bar.step[0].copy.map(s => ({text: s.text}))
console.log(sorted);
```

Then you could pipe

```
pipe(sorted)
```

Comment: You way is nice but have a single problem if anything if the path is not present it will throw error.

Comment: @MaheerAli Yeah, assuming it was correct and constant. Same with you really lol.

Answer (score -2):

The reason you get an array or arrays is because the `step` value can be iterated. Removing the 2 layers of array implies you are restricting only to a single value of the `step` array:

```
pipe(
  path(['foo', 'bar', 'step', '0', 'copy']),
  map(s => ({text: s.text}))
) (data)
```

Or

You want to concat all the `step` values to the single outer array.

```
flatten(pipe(
  path(['foo', 'bar', 'step']),
  map(step => 
    step.copy.map(s => ({text: s.text}))
  ),
) (data))
```